# Hostile takeover bid to turn company private - how does it work (current context: Musk / Twitter)?

Tags: stocks, shares, corporation, corporate-acquisition, private-company

With regard to the current coverage of Musk announcing his wish to turn Twitter into a private company, I'd appreciate some clarification:

Twitter stock, according to [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TWTR/holders?p=TWTR), is owned by various shareholders. Normally, a hostile takeover bid would be successful if a certain percentage of those shareholders would accept the bid (as far as I gather, it generally needn't even be 50% + 1 shares).

0. How can I look up what kinds of Twitter stock types exist?
1. In the current case of Musk and Twitter, when he says "private company", does this refer solely to a state where all shares are owned by one entity, or are there other interpretations?
2. If Musk were to own a certain percentage of Twitter shares, could he force the other shareholders to sell their shares to him? If so, what would that percentage need to be?
3. Can there exist a shareholder who owns a minority stake and who does not want to surrender that stake, so that he would prevent the company from fundamentally changing its corporate status?

Comment: Just FYI, being "private" just means the company is not traded on the stock market,it doesn't imply anything about the number and structure of shareholders. Lots of private companies don't have one majority shareholder.